# Website hosting in aws using ec2-ubuntu server

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I need to host two applications in apache2 using same instance,first application is hosted it working fine but i am trying to host second application getting the error "page not found" the url is not hitting the api's

Comment: There is no information in your question to answer anything. Do you use elb (which one and how), how is your apache setup, what about security groups, does the second website work from localhost.

Comment: How you are *trying to host second application*?

Answer (score 0):

1)Yes i used elb with acm certificate the first application that are angular and php applications domain is godaddy the second application is python same instance i hosted and same apache
2)I used ports 80,443,22